# Universal image Loader resizing imageview

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm currently using Universal image Loader in my app. I have a listview containing an adapter with an imageview. The problem is that I have set the imageview height to wrap content and width to match parent.
I've also set a placeholder (640x480) to when the lib is loading the image. The images  i'm using to populate the adapter are smaller than the placeholder and they should stay on the center of the imageview (cropCenter). The first time I open the app the imageviews are populated just fine. This is because the lib sets the target size of the imageview to the placeholder size.

When the image is stored on the memory cache and reused the lib already knows the displayed size (let's say 380x285) and when it populates the imageview it will get wrapped to that size making some views larger than others. When I disable the memory cache this behavior doesn't happen and all the imageviews will have the size of the placeholder with the image centercroped.

Since I don't want to disable the memory cache is there anyway to maintain the size of the imageview when I reuse images from the cache?

I hope I made myself clear enough.
Thanks

Comment: Show your configuration, display options, ImageView's layout.

Comment: solved the problem by changing the size of the imageview to the screensize during the getview of the adapter. Since the imageview will get a specific size the UIL will take that into account and the problem disapears